# The footer move when I scroll the page how can I make it be static at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

So that, practically, the footer would move if I scroll the page. I want it to be stuck at the bottom of the page and not move if I scroll the page I will show the picture to make it clear.

this is the first.
[image]

2nd one:
[image]

The css:

```css
.main_wrapper {

  width: 1000px;

  height: auto;

  margin: auto;

}

.content_wrapper {

  width: 1000px;

  height: 800px;

  margin: auto;

  background: pink;

}

html {

  min-height: 100%;

  height: 100%;

  padding-bottom: 150px;

}

body {

  position: absolute;

  min-height: 100%;

  height: 100%;

  font-family: verdana;

  background-color: #FFFFEE;

  padding-bottom: 100px;

}

#logo {

  position: absolute;

  left: 50px;

}

h2 {

  font-family: fantasy;

  font-size: 35px;

  position: relative;

  left: 300px;

  top: 20px;

  color: #FF85AD;

  display: inline;

}

#login h2 {

  font-family: fantasy;

  font-size: 25px;

  position: relative;

  left: 0px;

  top: -20px;

  color: #FF85AD;

  display: inline;

}

ul.sub1 {

  list-style-type: none;

  margin-top: 4px;

}

ul#tabs li {

  width: 125px;

  text-align: left;

  position: relative;

  top: 82px;

  left: 330px;

  float: left;

  margin-left: 4px;

  list-style-type: none;

}

ul#tabs a {

  text-decoration: none;

  display: block;

  width: 125px;

  height: 25px;

}

#tabs li form {

  margin-left: 1cm;

  width: 300px;

  height: 25px;

}

#login {

  position: absolute;

  top: 218px;

  left: 300px;

  font-family: verdana;

  background-color: #FFFFEE;

}

#product_box {

  position: absolute;

  top: 620px;

  left: 300px;

  background-color: none;

  width: 720px;

  text-align: center;

  margin-bottom: 0px;

  padding-bottom: 60px;

}

#product_box1 {

  position: absolute;

  top: 200px;

  left: 200px;

  width: 420px;

  height: 479px;

  text-align: center;

  margin-left: 30px;

  border: 2px solid;

  border-radius: 25px;

  padding-bottom: 60px;

}

#button {

  width: 80px;

  height: 30px;

  background-color: #A9A9F5;

  z-index: -1;

  border-radius: 10px;

}

#single_pro {

  color: #484A49;

  font-family: verdana;

  font-size: 10px;

  float: left;

  margin-left: 20px;

  padding: 10px;

}

#single_pro1 {

  color: #484A49;

  font-family: verdana;

  font-size: 10px;

  float: left;

  text-align: left;

  margin-left: 40px;

  padding: 10px;

  padding-bottom: 60px;

}

#table_admin {

  position: relative;

  float: left;

  top: 110px;

  left: 300px;

  width: 800px;

  height: 444px;

  border-collapse: collapse;

}

#phoneHeader {

  line-height: 50px;

  width: 650px;

  position: absolute;

  left: 800px;

  top: 70px;

  font-family: verdana;

  font-size: 12px;

  color: #484A49;

}

#phoneHeader p {

  vertical-align: text-middle;

}

#sidebar {

  position: absolute;

  left: 50px;

  top: 215px;

  width: 150px;

  height: 30px;

}

#sidebar_title {

  text-align: center;

  background-color: #FF85AD;

  position: absolute;

  left: 10px;

  top: -18px;

  width: 130px;

  height: 23px;

}

#sidebar_title1 {

  text-align: center;

  background-color: #FF85AD;

  position: absolute;

  left: 10px;

  top: 225px;

  width: 130px;

  height: 20px;

}

#cats {

  padding-bottom: 22px;

}

#cats li {

  list-style: none;

  margin: 7px;

  text-align: center;

}

#cats a {

  color: #484A49;

  text-decoration: none;

  font-size: 15px;

}

#cats a:hover {

  color: pink;

}

#buying_table {

  position: absolute;

  float: left;

  top: 200px;

  left: 750px;

  width: 500px;

  height: 444px;

  text-align: left;

  background-color: #D8CEF6;

  border-radius: 25px;

}

#buying_table td {

  width: 100px;

  height: 50px;

  text-align: left;

  padding-left: 20px;

}

#buying_table p {

  padding: 12px;

  text-align: left;

  font-size: 15px;

}

#buying_table h2 {

  position: relative;

  top: 5px;

  left: 200px;

  font-size: 20px;

  text-align: center;

}

#msg1,

#msg2,

#msg3,

#msg4,

#msg5 {

  font-size: 15px;

  color: #FF0080;

  width: 100px;

  height: 50px;

  text-align: left;

  padding-left: 20px;

}

#table_order {

  position: relative;

  float: left;

  top: 110px;

  left: 330px;

  width: 700px;

  text-align: center;

  background-color: #D8CEF6;

}

#table_order td {

  padding-left: 8px;

}

#table_order th {

  padding: 8px;

}

#footer {

  position: fixed;

  bottom: 0px;

  background-color: #D6D6C2;

  width: 100%;

  height: 30px;

  text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<?php include ( 'function.php')?>
<?php include ( 'flower.php') ?>

<head>

  <title>LilyOnline</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
  <meta name="description" content="LilyOnline Flower">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript,jquery">
  <meta name="author" content="Pegah">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="360">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slidePic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flower1.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="main_wrapper">
    <!-- headerlogo -->
    <div id='logo'>
      <img src="http://localhost/onlinesShop/calla1.jpg" alt="calla" width='250' height='120' />
    </div>

    <!-- header -->

    <div>
      <h2>LiLy Flower Shop</h2>
    </div>

    <span id="phoneHeader">
   <img src="http://localhost/onlinesShop/tel.jpg" alt="phoneHeader" width='30' height='30' />
   For phone order, or help choosing flowers call: <b>1800 5024 22</b>

  </span>

    <!-- main menue -->
    <div id="nav">
      <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="http://localhost/onlinesShop/index1.php?cat=8">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Help</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">About us</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="http://localhost/onlinesShop/flowerLoginf.php">Login|Register</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <form method="get" action="result.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="user_query" />
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
          </form>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- make a side bar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>

      <ul id="cats">
        <?php getcat(); ?>
      </ul>
      <div id="sidebar_title1">Price</div>
      <ul id="cats">
        <?php getprice(); ?>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Jquery for Slide show on the middle -->
    <div id='content_wrapper'>
      <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">

          <li class="Slide">
            <img src="hd11.jpg" alt="pic1" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="hd3333.jpg" alt="pic2" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="hd44.jpg" alt="pic3" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="04.jpg" alt="pic4" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="05.jpg" alt="pic5" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="ch1.jpg" alt="pic6" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide">
            <img src="06.jpg" alt="pic7" />
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Function for Jquery Slide -->
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          //configuration
          var width = 720;
          var animation = 1000;
          var pause = 4000;
          var currentSlide = 1;

          //cache DOM
          var $slider = $('.slider');
          var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
          var $Slide = $slideContainer.find('.Slide');

          //copy slide1 to last
          $slideContainer.append($Slide.first().clone());
          var interval;

          function startSlide() {
            interval = setInterval(function() {

              $('.slider .slides').animate({
                  'margin-left': '-=' + width
                }, animation,

                function() {
                  ++currentSlide;
                  if (currentSlide === $Slide.length + 1) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                  }
                });
            }, pause);
          }

          function stopSlide() {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
          $slideContainer
            .on('mouseenter', stopSlide)
            .on('mouseleave', startSlide);
          startSlide();
        });
      </script>

      <div id='product_box'>

        <?php getpro();?>
        <?php getpro_cat();?>
        <?php getprice_Cat();?>

      </div>


    </div>

    <!-- make a Footer -->
    <div id='footer'>
      Copyright© Roses Only 2014. All rights reserved.
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805590/css-sticky-footer

Comment: there is nothing wrong with footer when I press **Run code snippet** :-)

Comment: @Alex Footer is moving I want it to be static stays at the bottom

Comment: did you click "Run code snippet"?

Comment: so when I scroll up I shouldn't see footer at the top at the page But as u can see it will be show Sorryyy Can't really explain it better

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of the footer from `fixed` to `absolute`.

This will cause the footer to scroll with the page but I'm not sure that's actually what you want.

```css
.main_wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
.content_wrapper {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  background: pink;
}
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 150px;
}
body {
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: verdana;
  background-color: #FFFFEE;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
h2 {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 35px;
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #FF85AD;
  display: inline;
}
#login h2 {
  font-family: fantasy;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: -20px;
  color: #FF85AD;
  display: inline;
}
ul.sub1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
ul#tabs li {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 82px;
  left: 330px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 4px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul#tabs a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 25px;
}
#tabs li form {
  margin-left: 1cm;
  width: 300px;
  height: 25px;
}
#login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 218px;
  left: 300px;
  font-family: verdana;
  background-color: #FFFFEE;
}
#product_box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 620px;
  left: 300px;
  background-color: none;
  width: 720px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
#product_box1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 200px;
  width: 420px;
  height: 479px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 30px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
#button {
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #A9A9F5;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#single_pro {
  color: #484A49;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#single_pro1 {
  color: #484A49;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
#table_admin {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 110px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 444px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#phoneHeader {
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 650px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 800px;
  top: 70px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #484A49;
}
#phoneHeader p {
  vertical-align: text-middle;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 215px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
}
#sidebar_title {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF85AD;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: -18px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 23px;
}
#sidebar_title1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FF85AD;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 225px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 20px;
}
#cats {
  padding-bottom: 22px;
}
#cats li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 7px;
  text-align: center;
}
#cats a {
  color: #484A49;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#cats a:hover {
  color: pink;
}
#buying_table {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 200px;
  left: 750px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 444px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #D8CEF6;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
#buying_table td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#buying_table p {
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#buying_table h2 {
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  left: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
#msg1,
#msg2,
#msg3,
#msg4,
#msg5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FF0080;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#table_order {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 110px;
  left: 330px;
  width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #D8CEF6;
}
#table_order td {
  padding-left: 8px;
}
#table_order th {
  padding: 8px;
}
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #D6D6C2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<?php include ( 'function.php')?>
<?php include ( 'flower.php') ?>

<head>

  <title>LilyOnline</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
  <meta name="description" content="LilyOnline Flower">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript,jquery">
  <meta name="author" content="Pegah">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="360">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slidePic.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flower1.css" />

</head>

<body>

  <div class="main_wrapper">
    <!-- headerlogo -->
    <div id='logo'>
      <img src="http://localhost/onlinesShop/calla1.jpg" alt="calla" width='250' height='120' />
    </div>

    <!-- header -->

    <div>
      <h2>LiLy Flower Shop</h2>
    </div>

    <span id="phoneHeader">
   <img src="http://localhost/onlinesShop/tel.jpg" alt="phoneHeader" width='30' height='30' />
   For phone order, or help choosing flowers call: <b>1800 5024 22</b>

  </span>

    <!-- main menue -->
    <div id="nav">
      <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="http://localhost/onlinesShop/index1.php?cat=8">Home</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Help</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">About us</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="http://localhost/onlinesShop/flowerLoginf.php">Login|Register</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <form method="get" action="result.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="user_query" />
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
          </form>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- make a side bar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>

      <ul id="cats">
        <?php getcat(); ?>
      </ul>
      <div id="sidebar_title1">Price</div>
      <ul id="cats">
        <?php getprice(); ?>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Jquery for Slide show on the middle -->
    <div id='content_wrapper'>
      <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">

          <li class="Slide">
            <img src="hd11.jpg" alt="pic1" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="hd3333.jpg" alt="pic2" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="hd44.jpg" alt="pic3" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="04.jpg" alt="pic4" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="05.jpg" alt="pic5" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide ">
            <img src="ch1.jpg" alt="pic6" />
          </li>
          <li class="Slide">
            <img src="06.jpg" alt="pic7" />
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Function for Jquery Slide -->
      <script src="jquery.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          //configuration
          var width = 720;
          var animation = 1000;
          var pause = 4000;
          var currentSlide = 1;

          //cache DOM
          var $slider = $('.slider');
          var $slideContainer = $slider.find('.slides');
          var $Slide = $slideContainer.find('.Slide');

          //copy slide1 to last
          $slideContainer.append($Slide.first().clone());
          var interval;

          function startSlide() {
            interval = setInterval(function() {

              $('.slider .slides').animate({
                  'margin-left': '-=' + width
                }, animation,

                function() {
                  ++currentSlide;
                  if (currentSlide === $Slide.length + 1) {
                    currentSlide = 1;
                    $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                  }
                });
            }, pause);
          }

          function stopSlide() {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
          $slideContainer
            .on('mouseenter', stopSlide)
            .on('mouseleave', startSlide);
          startSlide();
        });
      </script>

      <div id='product_box'>

        <?php getpro();?>
        <?php getpro_cat();?>
        <?php getprice_Cat();?>

      </div>


    </div>

    <!-- make a Footer -->
    <div id='footer'>
      Copyright© Roses Only 2014. All rights reserved.
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: then it will be in the middle of the page @Paulie_D and if I give height to put it down for other page which has less data there will be an empty space It works If I define othere footer for other page like login page

Comment: As I said, it may not be what you want. You need to look into "sticky footer" solutions...a google search will find you many. It doesn't help that you are using a lot of positioning. There are much better layout methods. [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)