# div layout issue while printing pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf, css-tables

I am coding a lengthy div structured layout. I want the blue section independent if page height is short.

[image: example]

Comment: suggest you edit your question - I think you are looking for sticky footer e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805590/css-sticky-footer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to make a sticky footer. If you know the height of the blue section you can use the sticky footer method described in this [CSS-Tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).

Here's an example based on that method...

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.top {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to bottom height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.top:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.bottom, .top:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as bottom */
 height: 142px; 
}
.bottom {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <h1>Top</h1>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <h1>Bottom</h1>
</footer>
```

Comment: thanks you for the reply but i dont want a sticky footer, actually i m printing pdf, but when layout exceeds from its page height, its structure breaks.

Comment: How does the structure break? Are you trying to find a way to insert a page break in your html?

Comment: i want to separate blue section if page height is short. actually red and blue section is within a div for testing. i used this css

.page-break{  display: block;  width:100%; float:left }
@media print {
.page-break, .page-break div { display: block; page-break-before: always; width:100%; float:left;  }
 
}

Comment: Can you create a snippet in your original post to duplicate your code? It's not clear from your post what you're trying to accomplish or what problem you're having.