# Footer Sticks to bottom of page but overlaps content

Tags: html, css, footer

My footer sticks to the bottom of the page as I want it to, but as soon as there is enough content on the page to reach the footer, it overlaps said content. I've tried using a position of fixed and relative but neither have worked as I would like. I've also tried the other solutions presented on StackOverFlow but nothing's worked so far. Here's my code.

P.S. I'm not very experienced with HTML and CSS, so if I miss something obvious I apologize.

```
    <div>
        <footer>
            <p class="footer">&#169; 2018 The Chipotle Bandits. All rights reserved.</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

.footer {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uvyaes0d/1/)

Comment: See if this question can help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805590/css-sticky-footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805590/css-sticky-footer) if so please delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add margin-bottom to the body.

Add to your CSS

```
body {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the footer is positioned absolute and is removed from the normal flow of the elements.

In order to achieve this you could try to add a padding bottom to your content, basically to leave some empty space at the bottom of the content equal with the height of your footer.

From your fiddle:

```
</ul>
        </nav>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 2em">
            <p>Pleased him another wa..
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `height` of the footer, and remove `position: absolute`, or if you want a fixed footer, you can use `position: fixed`. I removed the margin as well.

Also, separate `footer` element style and your `.footer` class style. I renamed the class to `footer-text`. I centered the text using `flex` as well.

```
footer {
  /*
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  */
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-text {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give padding-bottom to the body exactly the height of the footer element because the footer is absolutely placed on the bottom of the container. So the content overlap can be corrected by having some gap at the bottom. Update the footer body css as given below

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: #363636;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-bottom: 38px;
}
```

Another scenario,
If you always want the footer to be visible even while scrolling i.e sticky footer you can use position fixed as given below

```
.footer {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    background-color:#363636;
    z-index: 10;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```